What color is used prior to the first SVG gradient <stop> element?
I have some SVG code for a linear gradient:
  <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="800" y2="800" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="0.2" stop-color="blue"/>
     <stop offset="1.0" stop-color="red"/>
  </linearGradient>

The gradient is along the vector (0,0)-->(800,800).  What happens colorwise along the first 0.2's worth of the distance before the first <stop offset="0.2" ... >?  None of the official SVG documentation explains this very well.  The gradient changes from blue to red in the remaining 0.8 of the way, from 0.2 to 1.0 of the vector.
Does the first declared color for the first <stop ...> element get used prior to that <stop ...>?

The behavior of a gradient outside the range of its first/last stops depends on the spreadMethod attribute.  "pad" (the default) makes the outside area the same color as the nearest stop; you can also specify "mirror" or "repeat".

Thanks.   But what is the default behavior outside the range if the "spreadMethod" attribute is missing?

Finally found the answer: "pad" is the default.
